# image-contain not fitting portrait image in parent container

Tags: html, tailwind-css, svelte

When the image is of portrait orientation, it will show with the width as the width of the container, even though it is taller than that and i am using object-contain in my tailwind classes. I am using Sveltekit, but most of the code is just plain HTML with tailwind

I have looked on stackoverflow and asked Copilot and Phind and cannot find an answer. I have used an {#if} block with calculations in the script tag up the top, where I check whether the width is more than the height:

```
{#if naturalWidth > naturalHeight}
                    <img src={$overlayImage} alt="overlay image" class="w-full h-auto object-contain justify-center" on:load={imageLoaded} />
                {:else}
                    <img src={$overlayImage} alt="overlay image" class="w-auto h-full object-contain justify-center" on:load={imageLoaded} />
                {/if}
```

...but this does not work

**My current code is the following:**

```
{#if $isOverlayOpen}
<div class="fixed top-0 left-0 w-screen h-screen flex items-center justify-center z-50">
    <div class="w-4/5 h-4/5 min-w-2 min-h-2 bg-black opacity-100 text-white rounded-lg overflow-hidden box-sizing: border-box;">
        <div class="grid grid-cols-4 border-0 gap-0">
            <div class="col-span-3 min-h-full border-0 items-center justify-center place-items-center">
                <img src="https://unsplash.com/photos/a-forest-filled-with-lots-of-tall-pine-trees-CRFqapQ0P0U" alt="overlay image" class="object-contain min-h-0" />
            </div>
            <div class="min-h-full border-0">
                <button on:click={() => isOverlayOpen.set(false)}>Close overlay</button>
                <h2>Ordering options go here</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{/if}
```

I'm wondering whether this is wrong code or something weird with tailwind? It's what multiple articles and AIs have told me to do but it still does not work for me